# Is this illegal copy of SO content?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

Today I found out this site while searching for some clarification regarding `NSBundle` http://t6942.codeinpro.us/q/508112064f1eba38a4facfd7. Googled for: [***why can't write to nsbundle ios***](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=why+cant+write+to+nsbundle+ios&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN534IN534&oq=why+cant+write+to+nsbundle+ios&aqs=chrome..69i57.6660j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=why+can't+write+to+nsbundle+ios&spell=1)

It seems to be a copy of this SO question: [Finding path to plist in Xcode project folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046370/finding-path-to-plist-in-xcode-project-folder)
If you visit that webpage, you can find it is copying quite a few questions(listed on right hand side).

---

Not just this, the home page of that site shows a complete list of questions copied from various SE sites. http://t6942.codeinpro.us/

Is this legal?

Comment: Nope, because they fail to honour the [CC:wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license SE sites use (attribute, link), that site is reusing content illegally. Please report it at the link Ben provided for you; it is not yet listed there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Shall I add these links as answer to question linked by ben?

Comment: Yes, please! Take a look at the other answers and provide the same type of information for this site.