# Questions closed as duplicates should include a link to the original question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, android-app

The Android app provides no way to find out which question the duplicate is a duplicate of, nor a link to it.

For example: [Is this illegal copy of SO content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196565/168660)

Tapping on the info button doesn't offer any more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [There's no way to tell if a question has been marked as duplicate in Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193059/theres-no-way-to-tell-if-a-question-has-been-marked-as-duplicate-in-android-app)

Comment: ^ Oh, the irony...

Comment: Technically not a duplicate. The notice requested there has been added; this request is for something beyond the standard close notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed as of the next app update, 0.1.33:

[image]

Comment: This does not apply for old questions that had the banner edited directly into the question...

Comment: By the way, when the target question has no answers, it is misleading to say "This question already has an answer here" and point to a question with no answers. And the "Closed as duplicate" info at the bottom even says "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question". I suggest amending the text when there are no answers. ("We're going to close this question as duplicate, even though there are no answers at the other question. Sorry you're just out of luck. No answers for you.")